# How to delete photos that haven't been accessed for more than 5 days?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a cron job which will automatically delete .jpg files from a particular folder that haven't been accessed for more than 5 days. Running the cron job is not a problem, but how do I go about writing the script which will take care of the deletion?

Comment: Make sure your filesystem is configured to store access times!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your filesystem is mounted with atime / relatime options you can use [fileatime()](http://us.php.net/fileatime) to detect the last access time.

So something like:

```
$dir = '/your/path/';

if ($fh = opendir($dir))
{ 
    while(($file = readdir($fh)) !== FALSE)
    { 
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
            continue; 

        if (is_file($dir . $file) && fileatime($dir . $file) < strtotime('-5 days'))
            unlink($dir . $file); 
    }

    closedir($fh);  
}
```

Comment: If not  tested (i.e. atime not implemented), your test will always evaluate to 0 < strtotime('-5 days'), which is always going to be true. Its better to store the result of fileatime() in another variable and check to ensure its not false prior to using it, else you'll delete every file in the directory :) Or, just test it once prior to doing any work.